# Форма на хэндлит изменения своих полей

Tags: javascript, form

На странице есть элемент `<form>`. Внутри формы есть поля, которые заполняет юзер, при скролле к концу страницы я удаляю часть текста JS скриптом и отправляю запрос с данными формы

```
  deleteUslessTextFromForm();
  var formElement = document.getElementsById('form');
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  await request.open("POST", url);
  await request.send(new FormData(formElement));
```

Проблема следующая: отправляются данные до того как текст был удален скриптом, то бишь форма не хэндлит изменения своих полей. Когда беру форму по id в ней текст до удаления остается.

Как можно исправить данный баг?

Comment: А вы уверены, что ваша функция deleteUslessTextFromForm делает то, что нужно?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko конечно, текст исчезает и визуально и если открыть html элемента

Comment: `getElementsById` → `getElementById` без `s`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, это псевдокод

Comment: Тогда нужен минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Вы хотите, что бы мы по не полному псевдокоду нашли баг?)